# GKE: how to close the connection to a pod after port-forwarding via bastion-host

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am working from my local machine with a database deployed in a pod in kubernetes. To connect to it, first up it is necessary to connect to a bastion host VM.

Basically, it is a double ssh tunnel: port 3306 is mapped to port 3306 of the bastion host VM and then to localhost 3306 port via

```
gcloud beta compute ssh my-bastion-host --project my-gcp-project --zone us-west1-b --command "kubectl -n mynamespace port-forward app-mysqldb-12345-abcde 3306" -- -L3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

However, when I terminate the command the connection between the VM and the mysql pod it's not terminated and I need to do it automatically: first up, in the bastion host,

```
ps -ef|grep port-forward
```

to find the the PROCESS_NUMBER
then

```
echo "kill -9 <PROCESS_NUMBER>
```

to terminate the connection.

Is there a way to close automatically the connection between the bastion host and the mysql pod when the `gcloud beta compute ssh` is terminated?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh my-bastion-host --project my-gcp-project --zone us-west1-b --command "bash -c 'kubectl -n mynamespace port-forward app-mysqldb-12345-abcde 3306'; kill -9 $(pgrep -f port-forward)" -- -L3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems not to work. I get a `bind: address already in use Unable to create listener` error when I try to reopen the connection.

Answer (score 1):

As @Saxon suggested, it is to run kill after the kubectl.. It should be killed first before running another port-forwarding operation.

So,You should perform another kill prior to calling the kubectl so it kills any lingering connection before creating a new port-forward, this will solve the error you are getting:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh my-bastion-host --project my-gcp-project --zone us-west1-b --command "bash -c 'kill -9 $(pgrep -f port-forward); kubectl -n mynamespace port-forward app-mysqldb-12345-abcde 3306'; kill -9 $(pgrep -f port-forward)" -- -L3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

Comment: Is the second `kill` operation necessary? It seems that the first one (before kubectl) just kill an open connection, but that the second one does not really close the connection.

Comment: Yes it is as for the error that you are getting

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it still does not work as expected; I still need to close the connection manually